# Setting the entry point for React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have been working to set up a React application, but i wish to use React Router `browserHistory`. When I do this, I receive an error that there are no routes available to `Folder/Directory/Where_My_Site_Lives_Locally`, this is obviously the desired behaviour for production when the application sits on the root of the domain, but how can I tell the router where to point in development on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory

In server side, return the index.html(except the assets).
`react-router` will parse the routes on client side.